# Difference between VOICE_COMMUNICATION and MIC in MediaRecorder.AudioSource

Tags: android, audio-recording, android-mediarecorder, android-audiorecord

I am using media recorder for recording call in android using `VOICE_COMMUNICATION` & `MIC` mode alternatively.

`RECORD_SOURCE = MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION;
//RECORD_SOURCE = MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC;
iAudioRecorder = new AudioRecord(RECORD_SOURCE, NATIVE_SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, RECORD_BUF_UNIT);`

I saw that `MIC` recorded audio data has gain much greater than  `VOICE_COMMUNICATION` (about 2/3 times) for some devices. Also background music captured by `VOICE_COMMUNICATION` is not as good as `MIC`.

Why do audio quality (like gain, responsiveness) differs for this two recording modes?

Answer (score 6):

According to the [Android Developer Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html) for [MIC](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html#MIC) and [VOICE_COMMUNICATION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html#VOICE_COMMUNICATION), some *pre-processing* like *echo cancellation*, *noise suppression* is applied on the audio captured using VOICE_COMMUNICATION which, in turn, causes some attenuation on the data. Moreover, on doing such pre-processing, audio signals with low amplitude becomes even more weak due to this attenuation. So we feel like background audio is sort of gone away for some devices when it is too low.

Another point was varied characteristics from device to device. From [this link](https://source.android.com/devices/audio/implement-pre-processing), it solely depends on device manufacturer and they are free to decide which pre-processing should work on which modes and how.

Comment: I have manually turned off the pre-processing by `instance.setEnabled(false);`,  but it doesn't work for some devices.

Comment: Low configuration devices like walton primo give almost the same performance(like gain, responsiveness) for both `MIC`  & `VOICE_COMMUNICATION` . But high configuration devices like samsung show the difference like low gain & low responsiveness for remote music for  `VOICE_COMMUNICATION` than `MIC`.

Comment: May be `instance.setEnabled(false);` doesn't work. Then how can I turn of the pre-processing ?

Comment: Again, manufacturer do have the privilege to alter API characteristics. I guess, in your case, that call is simply discarded for some modes and devices. I do have found different behavior for [AudioRecord.read](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html#read(short[], int, int)) on some devices.